# Copy files based on the extension length of the file?

Tags: cmd, copy, wildcard

i'm looking for a way on Windows to find all files with a specific file extension length and copy them to another location while preserving the folder structure.

For example lets say that I want to copy all files on my D: drive, with a file extension length of excatly six (*.******) and copy them to another location while also keeping the folder structure.

Is this possible in CMD?.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\PeterR>copy C:\Users\PeterR\Documents\cmd\???.txt C:\Users\PeterR\Documents\cmd1\

--use ? to specify the lentgh. for six characters it's ??????.extension

Answer (score 0):

What about the following code snippet:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=D:\"
set "_DESTIN=E:\"

pushd "%_SOURCE%" || exit /B 1
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    xcopy /L /E /I ".\*.*" "E:\" ^| find ".\"
') do (
for /R "D:\" %%F in ("*.*") do (
    set "EXT=%%~xF"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if "!EXT:~6!"=="" if not "!EXT!"=="!EXT:~5!" (
        endlocal
        move /Y "%%~F" "%_DESTIN%\%%~F"
    ) else endlocal
)
popd

endlocal
exit /B
```